# Vb.Net Skype4Com Display Pending Friend Request Usernames In Listbox & Send Messege To Group

Tags: vb.net, skype4com

I want to check Skype for the usernames of users that are attempting to add me. I will then send a message in a Skype group named "BETA" containing the username.

What I have tried:

```
    For Each user In oSkype.UsersWaitingAuthorization
        ListBox1.Items.Add(user)
    Next

    oSkype.SendMessage("BETA", ListBox1.Items(0))
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(0)
```

Comment: And your problem is? you need to post what it isn't doing along with any error messages.

Comment: @mark-hall Aha, what was wrong was in there but redditor edited it and I accepted the changes the issue is that it will not do anything, it will hook into skype but it won't go through with the requests as like the code I am using isn't the correct way.